# Minimizing Zend Framework to Zend_Mail?

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, zend-mail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use Zend Framework components without the actual framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402989/use-zend-framework-components-without-the-actual-framework)

I just need the Zend_Mail functions of the Zend Framework, but the whole framework is about 300MB in size. Is there a way to cut it down to just the basics and Zend_Mail to save up some disk space?

Comment: It's not big that much. Zend framework has 20-25 MB.

Comment: Well, then something is really wrong with mine. I mean, I didn't chose the minimal package, as I didn't knew if Zend_Mail was included, but it still says "295 MB (309,803,141 bytes)".

Comment: Why don't you use simply Swift mailer?

Comment: As far as I know Swift Mailer is only able to send mails, I also need to receive them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402989/use-zend-framework-components-without-the-actual-framework

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, I have used Zend_Mail with SMTP standalone before, here are the files I needed.  I also reduced it down to what you need if you only want to use sendmail also.

If you want to use Sendmail, that is the easiest.  Your dependencies are:

- Zend/Exception.php
- Zend/Mail.php
- Zend/Mime.php
- Zend/Mail/Exception.php
- Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php
- Zend/Mail/Transport/Exception.php
- Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php
- Zend/Mime/Exception.php
- Zend/Mime/Message.php
- Zend/Mime/Part.php

And with those files, here is an example use:

```
<?php
// optionally
// set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/path/to/Zend');

require_once 'Zend/Mail.php';
require_once 'Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php';

$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail();

$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->addTo('user@domain')
     ->setSubject('Mail Test')
     ->setBodyText("Hello,\nThis is a Zend Mail message...\n")
     ->setFrom('sender@domain');

try {
    $mail->send($transport);
    echo "Message sent!<br />\n";
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo "Failed to send mail! " . $ex->getMessage() . "<br />\n";
}
```

If you need SMTP, then you have a few more dependencies to include.  In addition to the above you need at least:

- Zend/Loader.php
- Zend/Registry.php
- Zend/Validate.php
- Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php
- Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php
- Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php
- Zend/Validate/Abstract.php
- Zend/Validate/Hostname.php
- Zend/Validate/Interface.php
- Zend/Validate/Ip.php
- Zend/Validate/Hostname/*
- Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp/Auth/*

Then you can do something like this:

```
<?php

require_once 'Zend/Mail.php';
require_once 'Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php';

$config    = array(//'ssl' => 'tls',
                   'port' => '25', //465',
                   'auth' => 'login',
                   'username' => 'user',
                   'password' => 'password');

$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.example.com', $config);

$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->addTo('user@domain')
     ->setSubject('Mail Test')
     ->setBodyText("Hello,\nThis is a Zend Mail message...\n")
     ->setFrom('sender@domain');

try {
    $mail->send($transport);
    echo "Message sent!<br />\n";
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo "Failed to send mail! " . $ex->getMessage() . "<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: That was exactly the answer I was looking for, thanks! I would vote this up, but as I'm new, I can't, due to <15 rep, sorry. D;

Comment: @Big-Blue no worries, I think you can still accept it, or check back in the future when your rep is higher.  Feel free to comment back if you have further questions.  I have working example you could download as well. ~drew

Answer (score 0):

Download the Zend minimal package from here.

http://framework.zend.com/releases/ZendFramework-1.11.11/ZendFramework-1.11.11-minimal.zip

It's not that much big. Uncompressed version is 23 MB. And it has the Zend_Mail class you require.

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't find any information about the minimal's contents on the page. Though 23MB is still not that small for the ability to send and receive mails. :P

Comment: If you really need to reduce this try deleting some unwanted classes. Let's say Zend_Pdf, etc. I think it won't make issues to your code. Or you can use some other email class written to use interdependently.