# PHP mail function missing characters

Tags: php, email, hyperlink

I have a really weird error with the mail() function in php.

This is the code i'm using to send the message:

```
        $to = strip_tags($_POST['newMail']);
        $subject = "Company: Update your email address ";
        $message = $mailHeader.'<b>Hello from Company!</b><br/> <br/> Please confirm your new email address by clicking this link: <a href="http://www.Company.com/confirm.php?regID='.$regID.'&newemail='.mysql_escape_string($_POST['newMail']).'" class="link"> Confirm Email Address Change</a><br/><br/><p class="p"><b>Thank you.</b></p><br/><b class="h2">Company.</b>'.$mailFooter;
        $from = "<noreply@company.com>";
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: Company Name" . $from. " \r\n";
```

To note, the company name has been replaced with 'company'.

EDIT - $mailHeader

```
    <html>
<style>
/* `XHTML, HTML4, HTML5 Reset
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

body {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.link{
    color:#81c6f6;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.link:visited {
    color:#81c6f6;
}
.link:hover {
    color:#f6b181;
}
.h1{
    color:#696969;
    font:20px/1.5 Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
.p{
    padding:2px;
    color:#787878;
    font:16px/1.5 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
.h2{
    padding:2px;
    color:#81c6f6;;
    font:16px/1.5 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
.roundAll{
    -moz-border-radius:20px;
    border-radius:20px;
    -webkit-radius: 20px;
}
#header{
    height:71px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#99d1f8;
}
#automarginwrap{
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
#content{
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:10px;
    width:80%;
    border: solid 10px #f1f1f1;
    background-color:#fff;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="header"><center><img src="http://www.downloadablecreations.com/images/logo.png" /></center></div>
<div id="automarginwrap">
    <div id="content" class="roundAll h1">
```

$mailFooter -

```
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now this works fine, the mail is sent and received no error message appear, however when i click on the link, it directs me to a url missing either a 'w' in the href part of the message (Mail.app Apple):

```
<a href="http://ww.Company.com/confirm.php?
```

Or a random letter from the link:

```
<a href="http://www.Compay.com/confirm.php?
```

Am i doing something wrong?

I believe the error lies in the charset aspect of the email or the encoding.

EDIT - removing mysql_escape_string() made no difference to the result.

Comment: cant imagine why you are using mysql_escape_string() in an email body. it may be worth adding urlencode() to the vars to see if that does anything

Comment: Updated the original post.

Comment: seems very odd can you post the rest of the mail code

Comment: Included the $mailHeader and $mailFooter code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that the line is longer than 70 characters? The [PHP manual states](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) that lines should be no longer than 70 characters.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11794786/1854627) may also be useful.

Personally, I've had this problem with some email clients truncating long lines of text, similar to what you are describing. The best way to fix it would be to either break the lines apart or use a framework or method that is better equipped to send HTML mail.

The manual recommends [Pear::Mail_Mine](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime). I would recommend something like Zend Mail if using ZF, though. Going with a framework will also help make your life much easier in the long run, especially when dealing with the many different mail servers and clients.

Comment: Thank you for this information, however the server package the client has do not allow for Modifications of the serverphp.ini config. Are there any simple .php files, that will turn my parameters into a nice readable email?

Comment: Thanks justin, I will try this out later on today!

Comment: I've only used Zend Framework, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9282936/1854627) might be more along the lines of what you need!